# Chamar método slide do slider - jQuery Ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Como faço para chamar o método `slide` ?

```
$("#slider-range-min-idle_timeout" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      min: 10,
      max: 60,
      step:10,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {

        $("input:text#idle_timeout").val(ui.value+" minutos");
        $("input:hidden[name=idle_timeout]").val(ui.value*60);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que diz na documentação:

> Desencadeada em cada movimento do mouse durante slide. O valor fornecido em caso como ui.value representa o valor que a pega terá como resultado do movimento actual. Cancelar o evento irá impedir a alça de mover-se ea alça continuarão a ter seu valor anterior.

Esse evento é chamado em cada mover do slide. Tente dar um console.log(event, ui) dentro da função para ver se está retornando algo ou se da erro.

Veja aqui a [Documentação do slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)

Comment: O plugin está funcionando perfeitamente mas como pode ver faço o tratamento dos dados antes de popula-los nos campos então para não reescrever o código gostaria de apenas chamar o evento na hora de popular. para que ele formate os valores.

Comment: Agora entendi o que precisa. Tem uma forma de chamar o trigger, mas não consigo testa agora. Veja ai e diga se deu certo:
$slider = $('#slider-range-min-idle_timeout');
$slider.slider('option', 'slide').call($slider);

Comment: Deu um erro `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` provavelmente ele não recebe o parametro `ui`